# Connect Cisco 3560x with LinkSys SRW2008 via Fiber

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, fiber

We have several buildings on campus. In our main building we have a core switch which is a Cisco 3560X (with a C3KX-NM-1G module installed) and a Cisco SR2024, among other switches. In another building I have a LinkSys SRW2008. These two buildings were connected via fiber between the LinkSys SRW2008 and the Cisco SR2024 switch using a Mini-GBIC MGBSX1 connector on each end.

Over the weekend, the SR2024 died (no power). I'd like to move the fiber connection in the main building to one of the C3KX-NM-1G ports in the 3560X. At first I just moved it, but the port immediately went to error. I removed the fiber from the Mini-GBIC and did a `shut` and `no shut`. That has removed the error. I then connected the fiber back, but the port still shows no connection.

Is there something I need to do to get the port to recognize the link? I thought it would do so automatically, but in my very limited understanding of the Cisco IOS, I was obviously wrong.

Can someone help me configure this link so I can get that part of our network back up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the MGBSX1 is compatible with the 3560X with the C3KX-NM-1G module. It seems these are the transceivers compatible with your switch:

GLC-SX-MMD
GLC-LH-SMD
GLC-ZX-SM
GLC-ZX-SMD
GLC-BX-D
GLC-BX-U
SFP-GE-S
SFP-GE-L
SFP-GE-Z
CWDM SFP
DWDM SFP
GLC-EX-SMD

See the compatibility chart at [Cisco Gigabit Ethernet Transceiver Modules Compatibility Matrix](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/interfaces_modules/transceiver_modules/compatibility/matrix/GE_Tx_Matrix.html).

Comment: Thanks Ron! It looks like the GLC-SX-MMD is the one I need. Do you have any other suggestions or warnings or comments that I should be aware of?

Comment: Are you really connecting two building with multi-mode fiber (not unheard of, but normally MM is inside buildings, and SM is between buildings)? The GLC-SX-MMD is a multi-mode part. With MM, you need to know the cable length and the fiber class to really make sure you can extend 1 Gb that far. With 62.5 micron OM1 cabling, you are limited to a cable length of 722 ft (220 m).

Comment: Well, now I don't know. What's an easy way to determine what I have?

Comment: I just looked up the MGBSX1 (by the way, Google is _very_ helpful with this). It appears that the GLC-SX-MMD is equivalent. MGBSX1: _1000BASE-SX SFP transceiver, for multimode fiber, 850 nm wavelength, support up to 500 m_. GLC-SX-MMD: _1000BASE-SX SFP transceiver module for MMF, 850-nm wavelength, dual LC/PC connector_. If it works today with the MGBSX1, it should work with the GLC-SX-MMD.